# How to make horizontal scrollable div in small screen

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple grid system for  my blog website, where I wanted that all the boxes or divs except 1st one will be horizontally scrollable in small screen (I mean 780px). How can I do it...?  I tried many ways, but unable.

What I want:

This is now I have:

[image: In Large Screen (Currently Have)]

This is what I want in small screen:

[image: In Small Screen what I want]

Here's my code:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.div {
  padding: 35px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.parent .div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}

.parent .div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
}

.parent .div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
}

.parent .div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
}

.parent .div:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}

.parent .div:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div">1</div>
  <div class="div">2</div>
  <div class="div">3</div>
  <div class="div">4</div>
  <div class="div">5</div>
  <div class="div">6</div>
</div>
```

Please somebody assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting that scrolling behaviour was a challenge, but here's something that I think gets very close to what you want, assuming you have exactly 6 items. Note that I have the container query set to 500px to fit in the snippet, but you can make it 780px.

```css
.container { container-type: inline-size; }

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  gap: 5px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.parent::before {
  content: "";
  grid-column: span 5;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.child:first-child {
  width: 100cqi;
  height: 205px;
  position: fixed;
}

@container (min-width: 500px) {
  .parent {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  
  .parent::before {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .child:first-child {
    position: static;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container" style="max-width: 400px;">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideas in use here:

- `position: fixed` keeps the first item from scrolling along with all the other items when in a small container.
- The `.parent::before` is used to effectively "simulate" the first element, since it now has fixed position.
- In Big Mode, you only need `grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3` on the first element, and the others will fill in the rest of the slots.
- [Container Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries), so that `100cqi` is 100% of the container's size and not 100% of the actual grid's size, so the first element does not need to scroll. Note that this is a relatively new feature, but it might be possible (albeit janky) to use regular media queries and `vw`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not what I wanted. You Have created same two div's or blocks. But I need to do it with just one div. Which will work responsively. I mean in big screen, it will show and in small screen, it will work horizontally.

Comment: To clarify, the two different div blocks there are actually the same thing, just demonstrating what one would look like on a big screen, and what one would look like on a small screen. One of the blocks is fully responsive on its own. Unless you mean that the `<div class="container">` part can't exist? In which case you could omit it and replace the container query with a media query.

Comment: Oh Sorry.. I Didn't looked it carefully... It works and I get what I wanted. Thanks man. I up voted and accepted ur answer... ❤️❤️❤️